# Unwrap numpy array stored in single cell in dataframe to rows

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy

I have pandas dataframe where I have stored numpy 1D arrays in single cells, so the full array is only occupying one cell. There are also other columns with single values, although I don't think that should matter.

My question is how I, somewhat efficiently, can unravel/unwrap the arrays and put them into rows? I have several columns that I would like to unwrap like this.

I can access the individual numbers by using i as index

```py
df['column1'].iloc[0][i]
```

but there must be some smarter way than looping through it all and inserting the values individually to unwrap all the values.

The dataframe looks as follows. Some of the arrays are horizontal and some are vertical.

```py
    column1            column2           column3
0   [0.012, 0.07, ...] [1.23, 1.92, ...] [132, 542, ...]
```

The desired output is

```py
   column1 column2 column3
0  0.012   1.23    132
1  0.07    1.92    542
2  ...     ...     ...
```

Edit:
After using Ian's solution I get the following output where all the numbers have been put into rows but the "formatting" from the numpy array remains. How can I avoid that?

```py
   column1 column2 column3
0  [0.012]   [1.23]    [132]
1  [0.07]    [1.92]    [542]
2  ...     ...     ...
```

Edit2: This is how the data looks in the original df. The reason is that its a vertical numpy array. If I do a `.shape` on one of the columns it returns `(1,)`.

```py
   column1              column2              column3
0  [[0.012]\n [0.07]]   [[1.23]\n [1.92]]    [[132]\n [542]]
```

Comment: Maybe this df.explode(['column1', 'column2', 'column2']). But if rows had different length of lists in different columns, it would work not as you want, I think,

Comment: That is odd. Would you mind adding your `pandas` and `numpy` versions to your question? And could you also share the `.shape` of one of the arrays? Something like `df["column1"].iloc[0]` should do the trick.

Comment: Please see the new edit. I get that it's how the numpy array is treated with each number in the brackets, I just can't see how to get rid of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## All Arrays have same `len`

```py
# python 3.10.6
import numpy as np  # 1.23.4
import pandas as pd  # 1.5.1

# setup
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
    data=np.random.random((1, 3, 2)).round(3),
).add_prefix("column")

print(df)
```

```
          column0         column1         column2
0  [0.271, 0.544]  [0.579, 0.329]  [0.732, 0.305]
```

```py
out = pd.concat([df[col].explode(ignore_index=True) for col in df],
                axis="columns")

print(out)
```

```
  column0 column1 column2
0   0.271   0.579   0.732
1   0.544   0.329   0.305
```

## Some Arrays have different `len`

```py
# setup
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame.from_records(np.random.random((1, 1, n)).round(3),
                                          columns=[f"column{c}"]) for c, n in enumerate(range(2, 5))],
               axis="columns")

print(df)
```

```
          column0                column1                       column2
0  [0.111, 0.691]  [0.215, 0.981, 0.605]  [0.696, 0.121, 0.531, 0.835]
```

```py
out = pd.concat([df[col].explode(ignore_index=True) for col in df],
                axis="columns")

print(out)
```

```
  column0 column1 column2
0   0.111   0.215   0.696
1   0.691   0.981   0.121
2     NaN   0.605   0.531
3     NaN     NaN   0.835
```

---

## References

- [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)
- [`pd.Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html)

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Just one follow up question. How can I remove the square brackets around each number in the exploded dataframe?

Comment: Square brackets? In the solution the square brackets are in the original `df`. The `.explode` method expands these into individual rows (the `out` dataframes). Could you an example to your question showing what you're seeing after using this solution?

Comment: Please see the edit. As I see it, it treats each number as an array.